# QR DETECTION WITH OPENCV AND VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, qr-code

I need to develop an application which detects QR codes through a webcam. I have been working with OpenCV and Visual Studio 2010, detecting squares in general. Then I found a library called "libdecodeqr" which you can use with OpenCV. With this library there is an example (the name is "webcam") to detect and decode QR codes using a webcam and it works succesfully, but if there are various QR codes on the screen or paper, the application only recognizes a QR code,not the rest. I would like to know where I can find the algorithm to detect QR codes (something similar to the "square.cpp" in OpenCV) or the steps to develop it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new in OpenCv and C++, that's why I need help to develop the application. I have been searching information, I have read the ISO/IEC 18004 and other documents about QR codes, but I don't understand very well the steps of the decode algorithm and I don't know if that algorithm is what I need to recognize QR codes through a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ZBar` library, it's also very easy to use and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190687/using-opencv-instead-of-imagemagick-in-zbar-qr-code-decoder) you can find how to use it with OpenCV. It works fine for me but you should be aware of the typo in the example:

It's `(char*)img->data.ptr`, not `(char)img->data.ptr`.

Comment: Just as an add-on; I made a reduced version of zbar with no dependencies and a working vs build environment (without the need for mingw/cygwin). It also includes a nice and clean interface, so you might want to give it a try:
http://code.google.com/p/zbar-redux/